# Extract matplotlib.markers symbol with its marker

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Matplotlib has a "marker" option that specifies how you want your point to be shown (e.g. "o" gets you a point, and "v" gets you triangle down). Full list is found here:https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/markers_api.html

What I want is to extract the symbol, using its marker (e.g., "o" would get me a point as shown in matplotlib link above).

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean "to extract the symbol"?

Comment: In the link above, every marker has its corresponding symbol, this symbol is shown on the plot. For example, if you said marker="v", per the link, the symbol would be upside down triangle. If you said marker="D", you'd get a diamond and so on. I want to get that symbol.

Comment: Your reply mimics your question, I'd like to understand what do you mean EXACTLY when you say "to extract the symbol", do you want the string "upside down triangle" or …

Comment: I want the symbol, the picture, the .jpg. I'd display that symbol in a tkinter interface. The idea is that a user can select the symbol from a list of symbols.